# Override GoBack event in default button not working

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

All pages have the default Button :

< Button x:Name="backButton" Click="GoBack" Margin="10" IsEnabled="{Binding Frame.CanGoBack, ElementName=pageRoot}" Style="{StaticResource BackButtonStyle}"/>

Scenario for Page Navigation as follows:

P1 -> P2 -> P3 -> P4

I did a override in P4 such that when Default Button click, it will goto P2.

The Problem:

When in P2, I click the default btn in P2, it bring back to P3 instead of P1

```
in P4

protected override void GoBack(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    base.GoBack(sender, e);
    this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(CustomerList2));
}
```

Comment: Try by removing `base.GoBack(sender, e);`.

Comment: It does not work. Is there an Api which used to clear the Navigational Stack?

Comment: Do one thing, declare & define all new back button click event rather than using the base class' `GoBack` event.

Comment: To make it works. I have override GoBack Event in every Page in which I need to specify where to go. this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(WhereIWantTogo)); I want to know if there a Clear Navigation stack When I am in MainPage?

Comment: WinRT doesn't have any provision to cleat the navigation stack but you can try setting navigation state to `string.Empty`. `Frame.SetNavigationState(string.Empty);`

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming (maybe incorrectly) that you want to go BACK to P2... If so..

Simply loop...

```
        while (Frame.CurrentSourcePageType != typeof(P2))
        {
            Frame.GoBack();
        }
```

Comment: It will be the same as my method of overriding which does not need to know which page I have visited. I am looking for any new features in Navigation Stack that provides Clear Navigation stack once I arrive at MainPage.

Comment: Why do you want to clear the navigation stack when you reach MainPage? Unless I am missing something, using GoBack() will clear it.

Comment: At First, I start from P1->P2->P3->P4, I did override in P4 to Goto P2. If I dont override in P2, I will goto P3. So, If I can go back to MainPage, I will clear all in Navigation Stack to Start All Over gain.

Comment: Sorry mike - I am having a hard time understanding what it is you are trying to do. Good luck.